# Why does $\lim_{\delta x \to 0} (f(x_0+\delta x) - f(x_0))=0$ imply $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = f(x_0)?$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Why does
$$\lim_{\delta x \to 0} (f(x_0+\delta x) - f(x_0))=0$$

imply

$$\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = f(x_0)?$$

I am confused how the book says this. Why is this true ? I am studying the definition of continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that $f(x_0)$ is a constant value, not dependent on $\delta x$. This means that $\lim_{\delta x\to 0}(f(x_0+\delta x)-f(x_0))=-f(x_0)+\lim_{\delta x\to 0}f(x_0+\delta x)$. Then if you know this is $0$, $f(x_0)=\lim_{\delta x\to 0}f(x_0+\delta x)$. With the transformation $u=x_0+\delta x$, you finally get that $f(x_0)=\lim_{u-x_0\to 0}f(u)=\lim_{u\to x_0}f(u)$.